# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.rest.core.util.Java8PluginRegistry' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

As part of migrating a spring application to springboot (2.1.7), I'm facing an issue for a custom **RepositoryEntityLinks** class. The below class was giving a compilation issue for the constructor argument **PluginRegistry**, hence I changed it to **Java8PluginRegistry** :

Before :

```
public class CustomRepositoryEntityLinks extends RepositoryEntityLinks {

  private final ResourceMappings mappings;
  private final RepositoryRestConfiguration config;

  public CustomRepositoryEntityLinks(
          Repositories repositories,
          ResourceMappings mappings,
          RepositoryRestConfiguration config,
          PagingAndSortingTemplateVariables templateVariables,
          PluginRegistry<BackendIdConverter, Class<?>> idConverters) {

    super(repositories, mappings, config, templateVariables, idConverters);

    this.mappings = mappings;
    this.config = config;

  }

  @Override
  public LinkBuilder linkFor(Class<?> type) {
    ResourceMetadata metadata = mappings.getMetadataFor(type);
    return new CustomRepositoryLinkBuilder(metadata, config.getBaseUri());
  }
}
```

After :

```
public class CustomRepositoryEntityLinks extends RepositoryEntityLinks {

  private final ResourceMappings mappings;
  private final RepositoryRestConfiguration config;

  public CustomRepositoryEntityLinks(
          Repositories repositories,
          ResourceMappings mappings,
          RepositoryRestConfiguration config,
          PagingAndSortingTemplateVariables templateVariables,
          Java8PluginRegistry<BackendIdConverter, Class<?>> idConverters) {

    super(repositories, mappings, config, templateVariables, idConverters);

    this.mappings = mappings;
    this.config = config;

  }

  @Override
  public LinkBuilder linkFor(Class<?> type) {
    ResourceMetadata metadata = mappings.getMetadataFor(type);
    return new CustomRepositoryLinkBuilder(metadata, config.getBaseUri());
  }
}
```

The Only thing I changed is the constructor argument, from PluginRegistry to Java8PluginRegistry.

When I add @Component annotation to this class, the application fails to start with this issue :

```
2019-12-20 18:16:33,491|11782|main|WARN|org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext|Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customRepositoryEntityLinks' defined in file [C:\com\custom\web\common\CustomRepositoryEntityLinks.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.rest.core.util.Java8PluginRegistry<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.spi.BackendIdConverter, java.lang.Class<?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 4 of constructor in com.web.common.CustomRepositoryEntityLinks required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.rest.core.util.Java8PluginRegistry' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.rest.core.util.Java8PluginRegistry' in your configuration.
```

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` doesn't expose a bean of type `Java8PluginRegistry`. This behavior will have probably changed with recent updates. If you follow the convention of how the regular `RepositoryEntityLinks` bean is created in the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` class, you can create a bean of your custom `CustomRepositoryEntityLinks` class as shown in the following code snippet (other parameters to create an CustomRepositoryEntityLinks instance omitted).

```
    @Bean
    public CustomRepositoryEntityLinks entityLinks(PluginRegistry<BackendIdConverter, Class<?>> backendIdConverterRegistry, ...) {
        return new CustomRepositoryEntityLinks(..., ..., ..., ..., Java8PluginRegistry.of(backendIdConverterRegistry));
    }
```

Comment: Tried this. Ran into this issue : ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field idConverters in com.xxx.CustomRepositoryEntityLinks required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.rest.core.util.Java8PluginRegistry' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.rest.core.util.Java8PluginRegistry' in your configuration.